# Bad operand types for binary operator "<"

Tags: java

Getting a `bad operand types for binary operator ">"`,

first type: boolean; second type: int.

In this line:

```
if( 0 < r < getNumberOfRows()&& 0 < c < getNumberOfColumns());
```

The `getNumberOfRows()` returns an int value, and `r` is declared as an `int` right above the `if` statement. No idea what is wrong.

```
public int numberAdjacent(int row, int column)
{
    int count = 0;
    int r = row;
    int c = column;        

    if( 0 < r < getNumberOfRows()&& 0 < c < getNumberOfColumns()){
        if(map[r+1][c+1]) {
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: No idea what bluej is, however it would seem reasonable to try `if( 0 < r && r < getNumberOfRows() &&  0 < c && c < getNumberOfColumns()) {` The construct `x < y < z` doesn't exist in any C like language I can think of but the intention could be translated to `x < y && y < z`.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Thank you! Adding a && helped!

Comment: @EmilyBlackwood Since no one else did, I added an answer as to not leave the quesiton unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a `a < b < c` construct to check if `b` is between `a` and `c`. Instead, you need to break it into two separate comparisons, `a < b` and `b < c`.

In your example it would look like;

```
if( 0 < r && r < getNumberOfRows() && 0 < c && c < getNumberOfColumns() ) {
```